# sql interogation betwen 3 tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

my question is:
find total salary which comprises from `contract_m.salar_baza+contract_j.onorar*contract_m.comision/100`
and `final` result contain name and `total_salary`.
structure of `tables` are:

```
contract_m:
id_cm
comision
id_angajat
```

-who have same value `persoana.id_p`
`salar_baza`
`contract_j:`
`id_cj`
`onorar`
`id_avocat` -who have same value `persoana.id_p`

`Persoana
id_p`
`name`

Comment: School assignment? Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

nope, i make for me in online some courses
i try this but is not good

`select persoana.nume, (select contract_m.salar_baza from contract_m inner join persoana 
on contract_m.id_angajat=persoana.id_p)+ (select contract_m.comision*contract_j.onorar from contract_m inner join contract_j on contract_m.id_angajat=contract_j.id_avocat) from persoana`

My table format is

`CREATE TABLE  "CONTRACT_J" 
   (    "ID_CJ" NUMBER, 
    "DATA" DATE, 
    "OBIECT" VARCHAR2(12), 
    "ONORAR" NUMBER, 
    "EXEMPLARE" NUMBER, 
    "ID_CLIENT" NUMBER, 
    "ID_AVOCAT" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "CONTRACT_J_CON" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_CJ")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
/`

CREATE TABLE  "CONTRACT_M" 
   (    "ID_CM" NUMBER, 
    "DATA" DATE, 
    "FUNCTIE" VARCHAR2(12), 
    "SALAR_BAZA" NUMBER, 
    "COMISION" NUMBER, 
    "ID_ANGAJAT" NUMBER
   )
/
CREATE TABLE  "PERSOANA" 
   (    "ID_P" NUMBER, 
    "NUME" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "ADRESA" VARCHAR2(12), 
    "TELEFON" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "PERSOANA_CON" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_P")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
/